# Prove that the sum of the Lagrange (interpolation) coefficients is equal to 1

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods

Prove that the sum of the Lagrange (interpolation) coefficients is equal to 1.

Please suggest me a book-reference or give a solution for me. Thanks a lot in advance.

If $f = \sum_{i=0}^nf(x_i)L_i(x)$ then one has to prove  $\sum_{i=0}^nL_i(x)=1$ where
 $L_i(x)=\frac{(x-x_0)...(x-x_{i-1})(x-x_{i+1})...(x-x_n)}{(x_i-x_0)...(x_i-x_{i-1})(x_i-x_{i+1})...(x_i-x_n)}$,   $i=0 \cdots n$

Comment: How do you define the Lagrange interpolation coefficients?

Comment: @copper.hat If one get a polynomial by lagranges' Intp method then sum of the coefficients of the polynomial is equal to 1.

Comment: $L_i$ is the (unique) polynomial of degree $\leqslant n$ that attains the value $1$ at $x_i$, and the value $0$ at all other $x_k$. So $\sum_{i=0}^n L_i$ is a polynomial of degree $\leqslant n$ that ...

Comment: @DanielFischer Not clear to me, please write in details for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $p$ be the unique polynomial of degree at most $n-1$ that passes through the points $(x_1,1),...,(x_n,1)$. Then $p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^nL_i(x)$.

The polynomial $q(x) = 1$ has degree zero and passes through these points.

**Aside**: The key fact is that if $r$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$ and
$r(x_k) = 0$ at $n+1$ distinct points $x_k$, then $r= 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let me propose one more method of proof.
"[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner's_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)", section "Lagrange interpolation", describes a determinant form of Lagrange polynomial that interpolates $(a_0;b_0)$, $\dots$, $(a_n;b_n)$
$$
P(x) = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0       & b_0       & b_1       & \cdots & b_n       \\
        x^n     & a_0^n     & a_1^n     & \cdots & a_n^n     \\
        x^{n-1} & a_0^{n-1} & a_1^{n-1} & \cdots & a_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots  & \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1       & 1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a_0^n     & a_1^n     & \cdots & a_n^n     \\
        a_0^{n-1} & a_1^{n-1} & \cdots & a_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}.
$$
Obviously, setting all $b_i = 1$ we'll get the sum of Lagrange polynomials $L_i$, because
$$
    P(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n\, \underbrace{b_i}_{=1} L_i(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n L_i(x).
$$
Now just simplify everything
$$
P(x) = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0       & 1         & 1         & \cdots &   1       \\
        x^n     & a_0^n     & a_1^n     & \cdots & a_n^n     \\
        x^{n-1} & a_0^{n-1} & a_1^{n-1} & \cdots & a_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots  & \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1       & 1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a_0^n     & a_1^n     & \cdots & a_n^n     \\
        a_0^{n-1} & a_1^{n-1} & \cdots & a_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
} =
(-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        -1      & 0         & 0         & \cdots &   0       \\
        x^n     & a_0^n     & a_1^n     & \cdots & a_n^n     \\
        x^{n-1} & a_0^{n-1} & a_1^{n-1} & \cdots & a_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots  & \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1       & 1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a_0^n     & a_1^n     & \cdots & a_n^n     \\
        a_0^{n-1} & a_1^{n-1} & \cdots & a_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}.
$$
Laplace expansion along the first row leads to
$$
P(x) =
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a_0^n     & a_1^n     & \cdots & a_n^n     \\
        a_0^{n-1} & a_1^{n-1} & \cdots & a_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a_0^n     & a_1^n     & \cdots & a_n^n     \\
        a_0^{n-1} & a_1^{n-1} & \cdots & a_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
} = 1.
$$
For practical example you may want to check "[Workbook on mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332971934_Workbook_on_mapping_simplexes_affinely)", section "Lagrange interpolation".

**NOTE.** Using Laplace expansion along the first column in the numerator you can get expressions for coefficients at $x^i$, thus determinant form of Lagrange interpolation can be quite convenient in some cases.